# Android volley cache requests

Tags: android, android-volley

I query my website very often; I have a REST service so I connect to *www.website.com/path/to/resource/id.json* and I use `Volley`.

In [this](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue#singleton) official guide you see that at the botton they suggest the Singleton Pattern. I am using it and it works very well.

---

I cannot understand something in the doc by the way. If you look at the above example in that page, they talk about caching and there is an "explicit" cache created.

In the below example (singleton) they are not setting up any cache. So my question is:

> Is the Singleton-pattern-way to use request queues going to cache results?

I care about cache because I call the same url (like www.website.com/rep/table/glass/7.json) many times and cache would save connection and requests. Is if enough the pattern to allow caching? I cannot understand from doc.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your volley request will be cached. Volley sets up a default cache for you. 
In the Singleton used by you, that happens internally in volley when you call

```
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx.getApplicationContext())
```

in getRequestQueue(), see Volley code [here](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/Volley.java). Cache is used you don't have to worry.

Answer (score 1):

Volley has support of in-built caching, the key of cache is the "**URL**" of the request. 
Enabling/Disabling the cache, setting the cache expiry time (partial expiry and full expiry) all such properties can be set using **Request** class method. For more customisation extend the Request class and do your customisation then.